# PL SQL more than single row returned issue

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-01427

I'm executing the following query and I get **"ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row".**
The error returns in the DECODE which is located in the main SELECT.
I cannot place the **USER_PRF_NOTIFICATION_T** table in the FROM section, as **USER_PRF_NOTIFICATION_T** may not contain any values. If it does than the values in **SEC_USER_PRIV.ENTITY_ID** do not all exist in **USER_PRF_NOTIFICATION_T.ENTITY_ID**.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    SEC_USER.USR_ID         AS USR_ID,
    SEC_USER.USR_FIRST_NAME AS USR_FIRST_NAME,
    SEC_USER.USR_LAST_NAME  AS USR_LAST_NAME,
    SEC_USER_PRIV.ROLE_ID   AS SYSTEM_ROLE_ID,
    DECODE (
              (
              SELECT
                  SYSTMTYP_CODE
              FROM
                  USER_PRF_NOTIFICATION_T
              WHERE
                  USER_PRF_NOTIFICATION_T.USR_ID = SEC_USER.USR_ID
              AND USER_PRF_NOTIFICATION_T.ENTITY_ID IN
                  (
                      SELECT
                          SERVER_T.SRV_ID
                      FROM
                          SERVER_T
                      WHERE
                          UPPER(SERVER_T.SRV_NAME) LIKE UPPER('%gen%') )
              AND USER_PRF_NOTIFICATION_T.ENTITY_TYP_CODE = 21), 1, 'SYSTEM', 2, 'TEST', NULL ,
            'ALL') AS ENTITY_SYSTM_TYP_NOTIFICATION
FROM
    SEC_USER_PRIV,
    SEC_USER
WHERE
    SEC_USER.USR_ID = SEC_USER_PRIV.USR_ID
AND ((
            SEC_USER_PRIV.ENTITY_TYP_CODE = 21
        AND SEC_USER_PRIV.ENTITY_ID IN (
            (
                SELECT
                    SERVER_T.SRV_ID
                FROM
                    SERVER_T
                WHERE
                    UPPER(SERVER_T.SRV_NAME) LIKE UPPER('%gen%') ))))
```

How can solve this? referencing the entity ID directly obviously resolves that issue.
I tried using **tableof** which contains all ID and trying:

**USER_PRF_NOTIFICATION_T.ENTITY_ID IN (tableof)** but I get the same error.
How can resolve this?
I need to create a correlation between the ID selected in the **FROM** section and the ID used in the DECODE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The parentheses in your query do not look balanced.  I will fix this for you if you verify that the above query is what is generating the error output you claim.

Comment: Could you please fix any syntax errors and format the code properly? It's very difficult to read.

Comment: @Drumbeg, done. Sorry about that.

Comment: What exactly do you expect Oracle to do when decode subquery from USER_PRF_NOTIFICATION_T returns more than one row? That's why you get your error. Make it so that subquery always returns one row (via distinct, group by or additional constraints for example), and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you added "NULL" in the list of key/value pairs and that is causing the error.

```
`1, 'SYSTEM', 2, 'TEST', NULL , 'ALL'`
```

Remove NULL here

Comment: But 'NULL' is a possible value.